# "Піднести печеного рака"

Tags: фразеологізми

[Мова- ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/frazeologizmu/vidmovlyatu-tomu,-xto-svataetsya)

[image]

Вирази про гарбуз -"дати гарбуза" та "годувати гарбузами" є в [фразеологічному словнику української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53395/356956.html)

> *Відмовляти тому, хто сватається.*

З СУМ-11

> [відкоша](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidkosha) - давати (діставати, дати, дістати) відкоша — давати
>   (діставати) відсіч.

Три вирази зрозумілі, а останій не розумію. Яке він має відношення до означення відмовити тому, хто сватається?

Адже в ФСУМ статті "рак" вказано

[**пекти раків**](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53408/360845.html)

> пекти́ / спекти́ ра́ків (ра́ки, ра́ка). Червоніти перев. від сорому,
>   ніяковіти і т. ін

Comment: Вм ж самі усе написали - осоромити та примусити парубка ніяковіти своєю відмовою

Comment: Чому б вас це зацікавило? Гм..

Comment: @finesoul я не подумала саме так інтерпретувати вираз